# I want to access ansible inventory value one by one in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have very simple use case. I want to access my inventory variable into playbook one by one.

Folder structure:-

[image]

So i run `ansible-playbook -vvv playbooks/deploy-sevice-sub.yaml -i inventory/inventorysub`.

**inventorysub** is this.

```
[dev]
host=127.0.0.1 user=test pass=test
host=127.0.0.2 user=test pass=test
```

**deploy-service-sub.yaml** is

```
---
- name: Step to push sub
  hosts: dev
  roles:
    - deploy-service-package
```

**role/deploy-service-package\task\main.yaml** is

```
- name: Print the gateway for each host when defined
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "System {{ hostvars['dev'].host }} has gateway {{ hostvars['dev'].host }}"
```

I can run command on those server one by one, i want to access those value only, no ssh connect.

It throw error

```
fatal: [nso_host=127.0.0.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {

    "changed": false,

    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname nso_host=127.0.0.1: Name or service not known",

    "unreachable": true

}

fatal: [nso_host=127.0.0.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {

    "changed": false,

    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname nso_host=127.0.0.2: Name or service not known",

    "unreachable": true

}
```

I don't need it to connect, just access value from inventory.
How can i access host one by one into my task file? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing your hostvars using the `hostvars` variable, you don't need to target the remote hosts in the play: you can write instead a play that targets `localhost`.

We can use a `loop` to loop over a specific inventory group (or `all`
for all hosts):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Print the gateway for each host when defined
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "System {{ item }} has gateway {{ hostvars[item].host }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.dev }}"
```

Given an inventory file like:

```
all:
  children:
    dev:
      hosts:
        node1:
          host: 127.0.0.1
          user: test
          pass: test
        node2:
          host: 127.0.0.2
          user: test
          pass: test
```

This produces as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Print the gateway for each host when defined] ****************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=node1) => {
    "msg": "System node1 has gateway 127.0.0.1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=node2) => {
    "msg": "System node2 has gateway 127.0.0.2"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Alternately, you can a playbook that targets the hosts in your
inventory, but sets `gather_facts: false`. If you're only running
`debug` tasks, the play won't need to connect to remote hosts:

```
- hosts: dev
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Print the gateway for each host when defined
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "System {{ inventory_hostname }} has gateway {{ host }}"
```

Which produces:

```
PLAY [dev] *********************************************************************

TASK [Print the gateway for each host when defined] ****************************
ok: [node1] => {
    "msg": "System node1 has gateway 127.0.0.1"
}
ok: [node2] => {
    "msg": "System node2 has gateway 127.0.0.2"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
node1                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node2                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```